# Accessing the pointer element inside structure using another pointer

Tags: c

```
typedef struct{int length,
int *buff}new; 

new* ptr;
```

How can I access the pointer element *buff inside the structure using *ptr ? Is the following reference correct?

```
ptr->buff=3;
```

Is the above reference correct, or is there any steps that i must perform to access buff?

Answer (score 0):

yes,  ptr->buff is the right format. But `buff` itself is a pointer too. `ptr->buff = malloc (LENGTH)` is more common and `ptr-buff=3` is rare.  Although this is C code, `new` is not keyword but in C++, it is. I would suggest avoid using these.

Comment: but in above case do i need to initialise the pointer *ptr to some address or can i use it directly to point to *buff?

Comment: You have to allocate using `ptr = (new*)malloc(sizeof(new));`. So that `ptr` points to some memory location. Otherwise it points to `NULL`.